# Merging cells from above in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I'm implementing some sort of merging functionality within my datagridview component, based on the MsFlexGrid (vb6).

Let's say that on two consecutive rows, i have the same cell value for them. Like

```
Row(0)    | John |
Row(1)    | John |
```

But based on vb6, i can set which rows will be merged. So, i could have this:

```
MergeRow(0) = false
MergeRow(1) = true
```

As far as i know, i'd have to look not only at the cell below, but above as well, so it would still be merged. One solution that i thought is getting the cellpainting arguments from the cell above. But is that even possible?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to acheieve

Comment: I use the CellPainting event to draw merged cells. But it works if you compare one cell with the next one below, not the next with the previous. I thought that i could use the cell painting arguments of the previous cell so i could merge them.

Comment: VB.NET or VB6? Why the question is tagged with both?

Comment: i'm implementing this functionality on vb.net, based on the same functionality that exists on vb6 (msflexgrid)